# Android Game Developers on Play Store

Tags: android

I was wondering that Clash of Clans, Candy Crush etc. are they being developed in Android Studio? Since i haven't seen any tutorials, i am kind of stuck at game development. iOS provides SpriteKit and its really useful. I couldn't find anything related to android game development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create one simple android game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773424/how-to-create-one-simple-android-game)

Comment: They are out of date. And i want to know how other game makers make it through the market, is it game engine or studio

Comment: Well, the google links are still valid. They point you to a lot of different game engines and possibilities on how to develop a game on android.

Comment: The point of the question was between using game engines and android studio. I am aware of those engines. What i wish to know is can we develop games like we do in xCode. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that game development for Android has various paths.
I will try to present some of them:

1) The most powerful tool for creating game is Unity Game Engine.
It gives enormous options for crating game (in C# and JavaScript).
What is interesting, you can create game for many platforms in Unity like Android, iOS, Windows Phone (there are 24 platforms that can run Unity Games!!!)
Please see this link:

https://unity3d.com/unity

2) Another option for creating games (but poorer that Unity) is Scirra
Construct 2.
That one is interesting because you dont have to know any programming language.
Creating games is based on instructions (which are converted to html after creating the game).
You can try it for free here:

https://www.scirra.com/

3) You can also try KiloBolt tool for creating simple Android games.
You can write natively in Java.
Description and tutorials you can find here:

http://www.kilobolt.com/game-development-tutorial.html

I hope that helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll be looking into them